# Laravel 6. Get all users who don't have contacts in one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to get all the users who don't have contacts. Lets say

my User model

```
public function contacts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Contacts::class);
}
```

my Contacts model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Expected results: 
   get all users who don't have contacts yet. for example, if a 4 out of 7 users have contact in contacts table and I want to get rest 3 users (which don't have entry in contacts table)

I tried below code but it is returning all users not only users who don't have contacts

```
DB::table('users')
            ->select(
                'users.id',
                'users.*'
            )
            ->leftjoin('contacts','contacts.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->whereNull('contacts.user_id')
            ->get();
```

my English is not good so pardon grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relationship absence

```php
use App\User;

$noContacts = User::doesntHave('contacts')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try